# Two variables and clear responsibilities or one variable with casting?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show

Please, advice me which of the two following approaches is more clear and useful to show and hide text with `ng-show`.

**Code 1:**

Controller:

```
$scope.text = false;

if (error) {
  $scope.text = "Error message";
} else {
  $scope.text = false;
}
```

View:

```
<div ng-show="!!text"> {{text}} </div>
```

**Code 2:**

Controller:

```
$scope.flag = false;
if (error) {
  $scope.flag = true;
  $scope.text = "Error message";
} else {
  $scope.flag = false;
}
```

View:

```
<div ng-show="flag">{{text}}</div>
```

Which code is simpler and better to understand?

In code 2 I can omit the `else` block, so the controller will look like:

```
 if ( error ) {
     $scope.flag = true;
     $scope.text = "Error message";
 }
```

==EDIT2 
Codes are in reaction to events, so i have to set them each time event is called.

Comment: **My Answer:** _Code 2_

Comment: In code 2 which is better you can remove the else part.

Comment: Shouldn't the else in your first version assign text=false? Otherwise the view will try to show the boolean. And why not just use an empty string (which is falsy) to indicate false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixing variable types in JavaScript is bad practice. There may be extreme cases that it is ok to mix types, but this is not an extreme case. If you are looking for a way to simplify your code, use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
$scope.text = error ? 'Error message' : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this:

```
$scope.text = true;
 if ( error ) {
     $scope.text = "Error message";
 }
```

Here when there is a error is return "Error Message" otherwise its true

Comment: `!!false` what would be the result then? And `!!` results in boolean values then casting is not good unless the value is not a Boolean.

Comment: `false` Means there is No error so it will return true.

Comment: after page loads, ng-show must be hidden, so text must be false.